# Spring Boot 3 OAuth Authorization Server with FederatedIdentityProvider(s)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

i'm fairly new to spring boot, and trying to get a deeper knowledge by building a production grade applicaiton.
My goal is to create a Authorization Server that is backed by multiple federated identity providers (cognito, google, facebook etc).

The problem i'm facing is that when my client tries to get a token from my server, the user gets redirect to google, logs in and then allows permission but then the login fails on the authorization server side cause it cannot find the OAuth2Authorization using the findByToken metehod as it was never set. Not sure what i'm missing?

Please can you help.

my apllciation.yml

```
server:
  port: 9090
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: trace
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          GOOGLE:
            client-id: "actual clientid"
            client-secret: "actual secret"
            redirect-uri:
```

my config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain oauthSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/oauth2/authorization/GOOGLE"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                ).authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

@Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                  RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository,
                  AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings) throws Exception {

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/oauth2/authorization/GOOGLE"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                ).authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
                .oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer -> resourceServer
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

    
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("oidc-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:9093/login/oauth2/code/oidc-client")
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://localhost:9093/")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .scope(OidcScopes.EMAIL)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PHONE)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();

        JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository = new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
        registeredClientRepository.save(oidcClient);

        return registeredClientRepository;
    }

    
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase() {
       
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .generateUniqueName(true)
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
                .addScript("org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oauth2-authorization-schema.sql")
                .addScript("org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oauth2-authorization-consent-schema.sql")
                .addScript("org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/client/oauth2-registered-client-schema.sql")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried going through [How-to: Authenticate using Social Login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/guides/how-to-social-login.html) or reviewing the [demo sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples#demo-sample)?